# Regarding select query in mssql and mysql and reserved keyword issue for table name

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

In mysql i have set this SET   sql_mode = 'ANSI';
my query is this:

```
select username, password from "user" where username = 'admin' 
 and password = 'password123'
```

and this query is getting successfully run in mysql and mssql.
But problem is I have problem in

```
Sqlcommand cmd=new Sqlcommand()
cmd.commanttext=:select username, password from "user" where username = 'admin' 
 and password = 'password123'";
```

and when i am using adp.fill(ds)
It is givin me error of sql syntax.

So how can i solve it.
Also remember that MYtable name is :=user
which is MSSQL and MYSQL reserved keyword.so how can i resolve this?

Comment: Could you sort out the formatting in the query in the question please? Difficult to tell what it actually is.

Comment: Inshort , Mytable name is user.I want to write inline select statement query in c#.but it is giving me error of sql sytax since I am writting table name "user" (with double quotes)since user is reserved keyword in sql.so how can I write query in C# now???

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server (as from the presence of a SqlCommand) then write:

```
Sqlcommand cmd = new Sqlcommand();
cmd.CommandText = "select username, password from " + 
                  "[user] where username = 'admin' " + 
                  "and password = 'password123'";
```

In Sql Server, to delimit reserved keywords, you use a couple of square brackets.
In MySql you use the backticks.

If you have a code that should work with both databases then you should look at this information from the property QuotePrefix and QuoteSuffix of the [DbCommandBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommandbuilder_properties.aspx) base class and try to format correctly your query using the appropriate characters

- [MySqlCommandBuilder.QuotePrefix](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-ref-mysqlclient.html#connector-net-ref-mysqlclient-mysqlcommandbuilder-quoteprefix)
- [SqlCommandBuilder.QuotePrefix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder.quoteprefix.aspx)

Comment: Yes,excatly I want to run this query under both MYSQL and MSSQL,how can i write in c# so that it run under both,can u please please provide me sample code.

Comment: It is a very large problem. Basically you should work with the base interfaces instead of the final classes (IDbConnection, IDbCommand and so on) then you could put as much possible of your command query in stored procedures with the same name for SQL and MySQL, or use two different classes that holds the command text for both databases and choose the one that you are working with. (I prefer the latter for better maintenance but it is opinionable) Luckily the syntax for passing parameters it is the same

Comment: Ok,you prefer me to user later technique but actually it is not fixed which will be use either mysql or mssql.so :( can u please provide me sample link or some help to kick on :)

Answer (score 1):

Use sql server with [*parameterized queries*](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html)..

```
Sqlcommand cmd = new Sqlcommand();
cmd.CommandText = "select username, password from user where username = @admin and password = @pass";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@admin", "admin");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", "password123");
```

Comment: User is a keyword, you'd need [User]

Comment: @ColmPrunty [No, it is not](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html).